# oval validation to valid rest api queryparam and pathparam

Tags: validation, oval

I am use the Oval validation in my project and i want to valid the parameter in the rest api. but Oval is a Object validation framework, i know it can valid java object, but how oval valid the queryparam and pathparam?

i have a rest api as follow:

```
@Get
public Response get(@QueryParam("id") String id) {
    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

when i add the annotation `@NotNull String id`, it seem that oval doesn`t valid the parameter. is there anyone know how to valid the parameter id?

Answer (score 0):

Validating method parameters requires byte-code enhancement or usage of proxy objects.

You can use OVal's [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) based Programming-By-Contract features for this, see http://oval.sourceforge.net/userguide.html#programming-by-contract

If your application uses Spring-managed services you can also use the Spring integration to achieve service method parameter validation, see http://oval.sourceforge.net/userguide.html#spring-integration.
An example can be found at [SpringAOPAllianceBeanValidationTest](https://github.com/sebthom/oval/blob/master/src/test/java/net/sf/oval/test/integration/spring/SpringAOPAllianceBeanValidationTest.java)